# How to extract specific text between the second and the third "_" with CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING?

Tags: string, sql-server-2008, charindex

How to write SQL script to get "Cabforce" out of "Email_Transport_Cabforce_NEB_Fallback_LB"?

I found solution below to get all words between first _ and last _ but failed to transform it to get a string between the second _ and the third _.

```
DECLARE @c varchar(100)
SET     @c = 'Email_Transport_Cabforce_NEB_Fallback_LB' 

SELECT SUBSTRING(
    @c, 
    CHARINDEX('_', @c) + 1, 
    LEN(@c) - CHARINDEX('_', @c) - CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(@c))
)
```

Comment: Your question should be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shows how you can build it: I've broken it down into pieces; you can see the logic and put it all back into one expression:

```
DECLARE @c varchar(100) SET @c = 'Email_Transport_Cabforce_NEB_Fallback_LB'

DECLARE @firstIndex int = CHARINDEX('_', @c) + 1
DECLARE @secondIndex int = CHARINDEX('_', @c, @firstIndex) + 1
DECLARE @thirdIndex int = CHARINDEX('_', @c, @secondIndex) + 1

SELECT SUBSTRING( @c, @secondIndex, @thirdIndex - @secondIndex - 1)
```

Comment: **bold**Many thanx!

Comment: It crashes when the string does not contain any _ at all, just one word...

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit long winded but you could do it this way. It finds the location of the first underscore then uses that as the start for the next `CHARINDEX` calculation. It then does this again for the third `CHARINDEX`. The results of the final two calculations are used as the workings for the `SUBSTRING`.

```
DECLARE @c VARCHAR(100); SET @c = 'Email_Transport_Cabforce_NEB_Fallback_LB'

SELECT
@C Variable
,SUBSTRING(@c,CHARINDEX('_',@c,CHARINDEX('_',@c)+1)+1,(CHARINDEX('_',@c,CHARINDEX('_',@c,CHARINDEX('_',@c)+1)+1)-CHARINDEX('_',@c,CHARINDEX('_',@c)+1))-1) Result
```

Output

```
Variable                                    Result
Email_Transport_Cabforce_NEB_Fallback_LB    Cabforce
```

If your output could contain no Underscores then use this one;

```
DECLARE @c VARCHAR(100); SET @c = 'Email'
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 WHERE CHARINDEX('_',@c) < 2)
BEGIN
SELECT
@C Variable
,SUBSTRING(@c,CHARINDEX('_',@c,CHARINDEX('_',@c)+1)+1,(CHARINDEX('_',@c,CHARINDEX('_',@c,CHARINDEX('_',@c)+1)+1)-CHARINDEX('_',@c,CHARINDEX('_',@c)+1))-1) Result
END
ELSE
SELECT @c Result
```

Output

```
Result
Email
```

Comment: _italic_Many Thanx!_italic_

Comment: You're welcome. If any answers have resolved your problem then feel free to mark them as the accepted answer.

Comment: I had some troubles with both solutions when the URL string does contain only one word, thus no underscore

Comment: @KarineGambarjan i've updated my answer to wrap it in an IF which checks whether the variable contains less than 2 underscores

Comment: Thanx @Rich! It works when declaring only one value, I put it in my query for DB that contains all possible values with underscores and without, I recieved error "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."